# Replace handles/locks on Novoferm garage door

Tags: lock, garage-door-opener, garage-door

We've got a Novoferm Canopy garage door, which has a plastic D-handle like this one:

[image]
(Photo taken from [this site](http://novoferm.co.uk/products/garage-doors/garage-doors-automation/).)

While certainly functional, it's not very appealing visually.  The door itself is Rosewood and cheap plastic on it looks rather out-of-place.  I know I can get a different colour handle, but I'd like to get a brass handle/lock combination plate, something similar to this one:

[image]
(Photo taken from [this site](http://www.avemoor.co.uk/spares-accessories).)

Or maybe this one:

[image]
(Picture taken from [this site](http://www.matthewdarbysecurity.co.uk/services/garage-door-security-parking-posts/).)

(I know these photos are for different type doors - they are for demonstration purposes only, to show what I am after.)

Yet, I can't find any handle specifically mentioning that they'd be compatible.  Does anyone know of any compatible handles/locks/etc that I could use to replace the handle the door came with?

I am comfortable with any required work - however there should be no visible holes left in the door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is looking to do the same... I contacted Novoferm - and they do have something similar to what I need.  They offered me the product below (the images are their original - and they apologised for the quality). It's a bit on the expensive side, but it's very similar to what I am looking for.

[image]

[image]

They quoted me the price of £75 plus £5.50 P&P.  Part number is 80349003.